# nginx Clear 301 Permanent from clients browser cache

Tags: redirect, caching, nginx, browser-cache, http-status-code-301

I foolishly used 301 instead of 302 for a particular redirect in Nginx

```
location /somewhere/ {
  return 301 /somewhere/neat/;
}
```

but now I need to change where we redirect too:

```
location /somewhere/ {
  # 302 now, lets not make the same mistake again!
  return 302 /somewhere/else/entirely/;
}
```

I can of course see this change if I view the URL in incognito mode or bust my browsers redirect cache, but are many users cannot see it without doing the same themselves. Even if we could reliably instruct our clients to bust their caches, we could only reach a small subset of them, and all the rest would be left with the old content.

Comment: Not super experienced w/ ngnix and ssl (so not sure if this answer totally applies, but) had this same issue and I just had to clear the cache on my browser to fix the caching issue. (In my case, I suspect was due to testing the redirect (w/ the old site) earlier that same day).

Answer (score 3):

What you are talking about is cache busting, and I am having the same issue.  All that you need to do (if I understand it correctly) is force a query string parameter onto the end of the url, and that effectively forces the client browser to refresh to get any "new" content.

One possible fix would be to append a query string onto the end of your url if that query string is not already there.

In your case, you might be able to use a rewrite that both "fixes" the wrong url, and also cache busts the original url redirect:

```
# Fix the incorrect url
location /somewhere/neat/ {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /somewhere/$1?cb=12345 last;
}

# Handle the new redirect
location /somewhere/ {
  return 302 /somewhere/else/entirely/;
}
```

The **cb=12345** can be whatever you would like, as long as it is just a query string

The only problem with this approach is if your location /somewhere/neat needs to still be an active page, as this would effectively force it to always go back to /somewhere